# Validating input parameters

Tags: c++, exception, testing, design-by-contract

I'm trying to decide if I should use exceptions, asserts or boundary checks in some of my code.

The program contains a lot of calculations that is dependent on user input. The program is running on an embedded system.

The code below is a typical example. The parameter weight_percent_salt should obviously not be negative and it should not be more than 100.

```
float Conductivity(const float weight_percent_salt)
{

    float sigma_20C = 0.0;

    if(weight_percent_salt > 16.2)
    {
        sigma_20C = 19.4;
    }
    else
    {   
        sigma_20C = 2.0487 * weight_percent_salt - 0.2352 * pow(weight_percent_salt,2) + 0.0187 * pow(weight_percent_salt,3);
    }

    return sigma_20C;
```

}

In this particular case I can restrict the user input to be between 0 - 100% and leave the code as it is, but other functions are not directly dependent on user input but rather the result of other calculations.

What is the best way to handle bad input parameters in these types of functions?

Answer (score 1):

Asserts:
  These are usually enabled only for debug builds, and will result in a crash.  Since they are commonly disabled for release builds, you may want to follow up with another mechanism of raising an error; as their primary task is to flag to the developer that the state of the program is one that the developer believes is not possible.
Clearly for user input, anything is possible, and this is not a suitable choice.

(Almost) Anything else:
  Is done for both debug and release builds; so for where user input is concerned, is far preferable.  Exaclty what the 'anything else' is, is dependant on exactly how you plan to deal with a failure, which is a matter of opinion largely.

That said, Exceptions should be 'exceptional' in that not only do they not happen often; which is probably not applicable for user input parsing.

Comment: The problem is that its impossible to predict every combination of bad user input data, and I have to have some way of reporting what went wrong. If I can't use exceptions (which I agree should be reserved for stuff like running out of memory etc.) I'm left with return codes, and they tend to clutter my code.

Comment: Given that Vittorio had highlighted about exceptions - I just wanted to cover asserts; as they are completely inappropriate for examining user input.  Regarding throws, no one said "do not use" - but "do not force" - ie you can make a version of the class that has return codes - and then a wrapper class that checks the return codes and throws.  (or even just put a flag in the class and throw depending on that)

Answer (score 0):

Do not **force** exceptions on the users of your class, instead **allow** them to do so if they want.

- Provide a `validWeightValue(x)` function that returns `true` if `x` is a valid value for `weight_percent_salt`.
- Make `Conductivity` assume that `weight_percent_salt` is valid as part of its contract.

```
bool isValidWeightPercentSalt(const float x) noexcept
{
    return x >= 0.f && x <= 100.f;
}

float Conductivity(const float weight_percent_salt)
{
    assert(isValidWeightPercentSalt(weight_percent_salt));
    // ...
}
```

The user can now use `isValidWeightPercentSalt` on its side to validate input and throw an exception. The user knows that `Conductivity` assumes its argument to satisfy the `isValidWeightPercentSalt` predicate.

```
float calculateConductivityViaUserInput()
{
    float percent;
    std::cin >> percent;

    if(!isValidWeightPercentSalt(percent))
    {
        throw InvalidPercentUserInput{percent};
    }

    return Conductivity(percent);
}
```

---

Note that I am not a fan of exceptions - if your design allows for it, return a *monadic error handling* class like `std::optional`, `std::variant` or `boost::expected` instead of throwing an exception. Alternatively, consider using an `enum class` of *return codes* if you don't have any extra state associated with an error condition.

Comment: This looks like a nice way of doing it. In my case the user input will come through a serial port using Modbus RTU, so I would just return an error code instead of throwing an exception if the input data is outside the specified values.  Thank you for you reply!

Comment: @Q-bertsuit: yes, definitely avoid exceptions if you can get away with it. `std::optional`, error codes, and similar solutions are in my opinion more robust as they make use of the type system and force the user to deal with them.

Comment: Nice, I'll look into std::optional, although the compiler for this particular project doesn't even support C++11.